# AWS RDS with SSIS ODBC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

How would you pull in data from an ODBC source using AWS RDS with SSIS.
For instance, pulling in data from an AS400 source. On-premises you would use an ODBC driver etc. How to do this using an SSIS package on AWS RDS

Answer (score 0):

did you figure out?
One thing I would say is that SSIS and AWS Aurora MySQL is a cool stuff but not many people are aware of the challenges.
this is what can do

1. create a 32 bit ODBC connection on your machine. 64bit will not work for SSIS.
2. I used Unicode version of ODBC. you can try ANSI and Unicode.
3. if using stored proc in SSIS then the syntax for calling a stored proc is {Call procedureName (?,?)}
4. Parameter mapping in SSIS starts from 1. So if you have 3 parameters in your stored proc then you should map then to 1,2,3
5. also make sure that you are using the correct datatype. For me SQL_VARCHAR was not working and SQL_WVARCHAR worked.
6. There are some uniqueness for Collate, characterset, 32 bit and last but not the least AWS Aurora MySQL is hosted on UNIX.

[image]